# Grouping by chapter in List of Figures and Tables with ClassicThesis

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, classicthesis

I checked extensively the forum and the net in order to solve this seemingly simple problem, without success. I know that there are a lot of posts regarding this problem, but I was unable to find the one that was fitting my purpose.

I would like to add an extra line inside the List of Figures and Tables when switching from one chapter to another, when using the `scrbook` class of ClassicThesis.

So for example it should be:

1. Figure 1.1
2. Figure 1.2
3. Figure 2.1
4. Figure 3.1

while what I obtain now is:

1. Figure 1.1
2. Figure 1.2
3. Figure 2.1
4. Figure 3.1

Here is the MWE that reproduces my problem, with a possible solution that I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029271/latex-make-listoffigures-look-like-listoftables-or-lstlistoflistings), which unfortunately doesn't work in my case:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{classicthesis-ldpkg}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\my@chapter\@chapter
\renewcommand*{\@chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \my@chapter}
\makeatother

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\chapter{1}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig1}
\caption{Figure 1 of the chapter 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig2}
\caption{Figure 2 of the chapter 1}
\end{figure}
1
\chapter{2}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig3}
\caption{Figure 1 of the chapter 2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{3}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig4}
\caption{Figure 1 of the chapter 3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: I think it's a bug of the package `classicthesis`. You should write an e-mail to the author. KOMA provides the option `chapteratlists` which is disabled. The package `titlesec` loaded by `classicthesis` provides the possibility by changing the command `chaptertolists` or the commmand `\ttl@tocsep`. Both fails.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but please also upvote it (this has to be done separately from accepting). Please consider also to upvote helpful answers to your other questions.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: actually, I don't think it can be considered a bug. In the 2009 version of `classicthesis`, it was possible to activate the `listsseparated` option, whose aim was exactly to group the figures and tables related to the same chapter. This option was disabled in the 2011 version, because of some conflicts with other packges/options.

@locktep: thanks for your suggestion. I upvoted your answer and I did the same with the ones that gave successful solutions to my previous questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`classicthesis` adds a `\deactivateaddvspace` macro at the start the `.lof` file. This macro does exactly what its name suggests, and so your patch fails. Looking into the package code, this behaviour seems to be related to a `listsseparated` option (and associated boolean) that is set to false. I wasn't able to set it to true again, so here's a brute force method: Define a new macro `\killdeactivateadddvspace` that will cause `\deactiveateaddvspace` to do nothing, and add the former macro at the *very* start of the `.lof` file -- I've used the `etoolbox` package and its `\AtEndPreamble` macro to do so.

Notes: I didn't use the `classicthesis-ldpkg` package as it is not available at CTAN. Also, adding the `demo` option to the `graphicx` package makes it easier for helpers to test your code.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{classicthesis-ldpkg}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\killdeactivateaddvspace}{\let\deactivateaddvspace\relax}
\AtEndPreamble{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\killdeactivateaddvspace}}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\chapter{1}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig1}
\caption{Figure 1 of the chapter 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig2}
\caption{Figure 2 of the chapter 1}
\end{figure}
1
\chapter{2}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig3}
\caption{Figure 1 of the chapter 2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{3}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{fig4}
\caption{Figure 1 of the chapter 3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I wasn't aware that `classicthesis` was loading a specific command to deactivate the spacing between one chapter and the other. Good to know!