# Remove spacing between per-chapter figures in LoF

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

When I'm generating a List of Figures in my project, all figures are grouped by chapter. I would like to have the whole list without any additional new lines between different chapters.

How it looks like:

```
Figure 1.1 
Figure 1.2

Figure 2.1

Figure 3.1 
Figure 3.2
```

How it should:

```
Figure 1.1 
Figure 1.2
Figure 2.1
Figure 3.1 
Figure 3.2
```

I tried to apply the following solutions but failed completely :

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51074
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51880

My main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,utf8x]{report}

\usepackage{times,a4wide,multirow,tabularx,graphicx} 
\usepackage{psfrag,fancyhdr,longtable}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{belowskip=10pt}

\usepackage[left=4cm,top=2cm,right=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\nouppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 30pt
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\linespread{1.3} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\label{sec:First}
\input{chapter1/chapter1}

\chapter{Second}
\label{sec:Second}
\input{chapter2/chapter2}

\chapter{Third}
\label{sec:Third}
\input{chapter3/chapter3}

\relsize{-1}
\listoffigures
\normalsize

\bibliography{praca_mgr}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The two linked answers deal with different situations: the `classicthesis` package and the `scrreprt` class feature a way for disabling the added space, while `report` doesn't. Don't load `a4wide` which is dangerous; also `times` should be `mathptmx`; remove the `utf8x` option from the `\documentclass` line. Do you really need `psfrag`? If not leave it alone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is done automatically when you call `\chapter`, as can be seen from its definition in [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls):

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% <-- Gap in LoF
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% <-- Gap in LoT
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

Add the following to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<succes>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother
```

The above patch removes the insertion of `\addvspace` to both the LoF and the LoT; the cause of the additional gap between entries on a per-chapter basis.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\insertfigure}{\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<succes>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{A chapter}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\chapter{A chapter}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\chapter{A chapter}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\chapter{A chapter}\insertfigure\insertfigure\insertfigure
\end{document}
```

You can choose to use either both or only one by commenting out the required patch. An easier patch to remove both gap insertions would be

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\def\@gobblesix#1#2#3#4#5#6{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\chaptermark{#1}}% <search>
  {\chaptermark{#1}\@gobblesix}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Comment: I had to solve the same problem. However my file originally used package bm, and this solution (using etoolbox) would not work. The workaround was to use \mathbf instead of \bm. It works now.

Comment: None of these patches worked for me, but disabling `\addvspace` in the list of figures worked: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/793/88028

Comment: @Antoine: These patches will only work if the `<search>` term is found. If you're using a different class, then the construction of the `<cmd>` macro might be different and not contain the `<search>` term exactly.

Comment: @Werner: I see. I'm indeed using a custom class, but there is `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%` under the `\@chapter` command. Anyway, it's not a big deal :)

Answer (score 10):

This is a quick and dirty solution that works for tufte-book, and doesn't require any additional packages. I just temporarily overwrite the `\addvspace` command with a dummy command. Important is to reverse back to the old definition for the rest of the document.

```
 \let\origaddvspace\addvspace
 \renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{}
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables
 \renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{\origaddvspace{#1}}
```

Comment: The question was about the `report` class and the spacings there. While your solution might work as well, you should elaborate a little bit on it and provide an example

Comment: Your trick works wonderfully. But there is a easier way to do it: `{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}`, i.e., enclosing the renewcommand in a group `{}` will automatically undo it once the group ends.

Comment: This worked for me. You're a godsend!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the cleanest solution. This solved my problem.

```
\usepackage[figurewithin=none]{caption}
```