# List of figures in report document

Tags: table-of-contents

I have my list of figures And tables appearing like:

```
List of figures 
Figure 2.2 dummy figure 1
Figure 2.3 dummy figure 2
List of tables 
Table 4.3 the only table
```

Without figure  pages indicated. I want it to appear like

[image]

With pages

[image]
[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sw! please provide complete small document with which produce LoF and LoT.  and clarify, how both list should looks (your image of lists is different from your description (as i understand it).

Comment: The images I have used are just examples appearance of pages e.g in later list there is; Three dimensional graph.............................2

Comment: and you expect that someone will write code for you from scratch? maybe will someone do this, but usual question of type "do-it-for-me" (as your question looks now) are not answered ...

Comment: I want it like; Figure 2.1 dummy figure 1. . . . . ..8

Comment: @Leinah: The display you desire is the default behaviour under many classes. If you're not receiving this output, then you must be using a class or additional package that changes it. In that regard, it would be helpful if you could supply a minimal example that replicates this non-default behaviour. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, allowing us to copy-and-paste-and-compile your code and replicate the issue.

Comment: There are my codes

Comment: Thanks much @esdd the first answer is working  again thanks

Comment: @Leinah If my answer does help then you can upvote it (and maybe accept it).

Comment: Sorry, it was helpful I realized I was forgetting one important code, plus the additional codes you provided thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
  \renewcommand\contentsname{Table-of-contents}%
}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}% to add the LoF etc to ToC

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=0pt,
  dynnumwidth,
  entryformat=\figureentryformat
]{tocline}{figure}
\newcommand*\figureentryformat[1]{\figurename~#1}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=0pt,
  dynnumwidth,
  entryformat=\tableentryformat
]{tocline}{table}
\newcommand*\tableentryformat[1]{\tablename~#1}

% to remove the chapter gap in LoF and LoT (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121881/43317)
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\@gobblesix#1#2#3#4#5#6{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\chaptermark{#1}}% <search>
  {\chaptermark{#1}\@gobblesix}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\usepackage{mwe}% only for dummy text and example images
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{First chapter}
\Blindtext

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\caption{dummy fig 2}%
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\Blindtext

\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\caption{dummy fig 2}%
\end{figure}

\Blindtext[2]

\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\caption{dummy fig 3}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

Or if you can use KOMA-Script class `scrreprt`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
  chapterprefix,
  sfdefaults=false,% needs version 3.39 or newer, replaces egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles
  listof=nochaptergap,
  listof=entryprefix
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\contentsname}{Table-of-contents}

\usepackage{mwe}% only for dummy text and example images
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{First chapter}
\Blindtext

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\caption{dummy fig 2}%
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\Blindtext

\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\caption{dummy fig 2}%
\end{figure}

\Blindtext[2]

\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\caption{dummy fig 3}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]