# Vertical spacing in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to arrange the vertical space between the figures as shown in the
[image]

I do not know what the presence of this type of space is due.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121879/remove-spacing-between-per-chapter-figures-in-lof helps, but without a MWE that tells us which documentclass you use, this is just a guess

Answer (score 1):

You don't give an MWE so I can only guess that you are using a class that does not provide `\chapter`. For instance the `book`, `report`, `memoir`, ... classes provide a `\chapter` command which inserts a 10pt vertical space into the LoF and LoT. Try this

```
\newcommand*{\insertloftspace}{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}
```

which will insert 10pt vertical space into the LoF and LoT. Assuming that you are using `\section` then calling this after each `\section` will insert the spaces you are after.

```
% preamble
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{First} \insertloftspace
% text, figures and tables
\section{Second} \insertloftspace
% text, figures and tables
% and so on
\end{document}
```