# `\listoffigures` automatically inserts an unwanted space between figures of distinct chapters

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]

As you see from the image above, the spacing between the entries of Figures 1.3 and 2.1 are not the same as the spacing between entries of figures of the same chapter. Similar thing applies to the list of tables. I want the spacing to be exactly equal for all entries

The solution in [Remove spacing between per-chapter figures in LoF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121879/remove-spacing-between-per-chapter-figures-in-lof)
 does not work here. Try adding this to the example below

```
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
    \patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother
```

You will get the same output. I think this is because the example in the previous question did not have `tocloft` package in it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}



    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

% BEGIN_FOLD

    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=false,inner=1.05in,outer=1.05in,includemp=true,asymmetric=true,bindingoffset=0mm,marginparsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm}
    \geometry{bottom=0.9in,vmarginratio=3:5,includehead=true, includefoot=true,headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt,footskip=10.9mm}

% END_FOLD

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[TS1]{fontenc}
    \setmainfont{Georgia}

    \usepackage[Omega]{gensymb}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}

    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=DodgerBlue2}

    % ========== Table of Content Packages ==========
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \usepackage{tocloft}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    % TOC customization

        % Set lengths
        \newlength{\toclabeltonamel}
        \setlength{\toclabeltonamel}{2mm} % length from label to the name of title
        \newlength{\toclineskipl}
        \setlength{\toclineskipl}{0.5\baselineskip} % nominal skip betweek lines

        % Spacing

            % Chapters, sections, and subsections
            \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{1.5\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0mm}

            % Main title
            \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0\toclineskipl} % (default: around 9\toclineskipl)
            \setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{5\toclineskipl} % (default: around 7\toclineskipl)

            % Spacing between lines
            \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}} % for spacing after each entry
            \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}} % for spacing after each entry
            \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}} % for spacing after each entry


        % Entries indentations

            % Labels widths
            \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0mm}

            \newlength{\widthcftsecnumwidth}
            \setlength{\widthcftsecnumwidth}{\widthof{1.2.3.~}}
            \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{\widthcftsecnumwidth}

            \newlength{\widthcftsubsecnumwidth}
            \setlength{\widthcftsubsecnumwidth}{\widthof{1.2.3.~~}}
            \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{\widthcftsubsecnumwidth}

            % prelabel content
            \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername}
            \renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{}
            \renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{}

            % Post label contents (usually empty space or new line)
            \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}\par} 

            % Labels indentations
            \setlength{\cftchapindent}{0mm}
            \setlength{\cftsecindent}{\widthof{\cftchapaftersnumb}}
            \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{\cftsecindent + \widthof{\cftsecaftersnumb} + \cftsecnumwidth}

                % amount of left margin to the label

        % Margins (see the LateX Companion, 51 for more details)


            \cftsetpnumwidth{8mm}

            \cftsetrmarg{2.5em plus 1fil}

        % Fonts

            % Definitions
            \newcommand{\toctitlefont}{\Large \bfseries} % font of the titles of lists (e.g., List of Tables)
            \newcommand{\tocchapfont}{\large \bfseries}
            \newcommand{\tocchappagefont}{\large \bfseries}
            \newcommand{\tocsecpagefont}{\large}
            \newcommand{\tocsubsecpagefont}{\normalfont} 

            % Titles and labels
            \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\toctitlefont}
            \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\tocchapfont}   
            \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\large} 
            \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont} 

            % Numbering
            \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\tocchappagefont}   
            \renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\tocsecpagefont} 
            \renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\tocsubsecpagefont} 

        % Dots and spacing

            % Definitions
            \newcommand{\tocchapleaderformat}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
            \newcommand{\tocsecleaderformat}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

            % Dots
            \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\tocchapleaderformat}

                % To remove chapters dots from LoF and LoT, use 
                % \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\hfill}
                % Before \listoffigures and \listoftables

                % Leaders are also available for parts, sections, subsections, figures, and tables

            \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\tocsecleaderformat}

        % Names
        \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\color{\colorlink}\chaptername~} % chapter names
        \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\uppercase{Table of Contents}}
        \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\uppercase{List of Figures}}
        \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\uppercase{List of Tables}}

    % LoF and LoT customization

        % Spacing

            % Chapters, sections, and subsections
            \setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{\toclineskipl}

            % Main title
            \setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{5\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{5\toclineskipl}

            % Spacing between lines
            \renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}}
            \renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}}

        % Entries indentations

            % Labels widths
            \newlength{\widthcftfignumwidth}
            \setlength{\widthcftfignumwidth}{\widthof{1.2.3~}}
            \setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\widthcftfignumwidth}

            \newlength{\widthcfttabnumwidth}
            \setlength{\widthcfttabnumwidth}{\widthof{1.2.3~}}
            \setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\widthcfttabnumwidth}

            % Labels indentations
            \setlength{\cftfigindent}{0mm}
            \setlength{\cfttabindent}{0mm}

                % amount of left margin to the label

        % Fonts

            % Titles and labels
            \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\toctitlefont}
            \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\tocsecpagefont} 
            \renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\toctitlefont}
            \renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\tocsecpagefont} 

            % Numbering
            \renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\tocsecpagefont} 
            \renewcommand{\cfttabpagefont}{\tocsecpagefont} 

        % link colors
        \newcommand{\colorlink}{DodgerBlue3}


% END_FOLD

% END_FOLD



\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter
{
\centering
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\listoftables

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
}

\mainmatter

\newcommand{\figureandtable}{

\begin{figure}

    \caption{Impact of impedance ratios with different angles in the same quadrant on grid strength at the reference POI.}

\end{figure}

\begin{table}

    \caption{Top Five Weakest Combinations of POIs Identified with Exhaustive Search Method and the Proposed Method}

\end{table}

}



\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Background}

\subsection{Review of Control or Compensation Based Techniques to Mitigate Grid Weakness Symptoms}

\section{Background About Round-Off Errors During the Inversion of Ill-Conditioned Matrices}

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\figureandtable



\chapter{A Method to Identify Weak Points of Interconnection of Renewable Energy Resources}

\section{Proposed Method to Update ${Z}_{bus}$ to Account for Changes in the Series Impedance of a Branch}

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\chapter{Vector-Based Approach to Analyze Transmission Network Effect on Interaction Among Renewables}

\section{A Mathematical Basis for Understanding the Relationship Between Interaction and Structural Changes in Power Grid}

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\subsection{Combined Effect of $\bar{w}_{ij}$ Angle and Magnitude Near When its Angle is Near $\pm 90^{\degree}$}



\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa. The solution there does not work for me.

Try writing `\makeatletter
   \patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
   \patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
  \makeatother`

You will get the same output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove spacing between per-chapter figures in LoF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121879/remove-spacing-between-per-chapter-figures-in-lof)

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh True, but it's not because of `report` instead of `book`. Their definition of `\chapter` is the same. Apparently `tocloft` is interfering more than I thought.

Comment: @Raaja I retracted my close vote because `tocloft` is also at work here. This changes things.

Comment: @campa. Thank you for the comment. It really seems that `tocloft` modifies`\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}` that is added when using `\chapter`

Comment: @campa I have retracted mine too. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use `{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}\listoffigures}` and `{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}\listoftables}`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}


    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

% BEGIN_FOLD

    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=false,inner=1.05in,outer=1.05in,includemp=true,asymmetric=true,bindingoffset=0mm,marginparsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm}
    \geometry{bottom=0.9in,vmarginratio=3:5,includehead=true, includefoot=true,headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt,footskip=10.9mm}

% END_FOLD

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[TS1]{fontenc}
    \setmainfont{Georgia}

    \usepackage[Omega]{gensymb}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}

    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=DodgerBlue2}

    % ========== Table of Content Packages ==========
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \usepackage{tocloft}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    % TOC customization

        % Set lengths
        \newlength{\toclabeltonamel}
        \setlength{\toclabeltonamel}{2mm} % length from label to the name of title
        \newlength{\toclineskipl}
        \setlength{\toclineskipl}{0.5\baselineskip} % nominal skip betweek lines

        % Spacing

            % Chapters, sections, and subsections
            \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{1.5\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0mm}

            % Main title
            \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0\toclineskipl} % (default: around 9\toclineskipl)
            \setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{5\toclineskipl} % (default: around 7\toclineskipl)

            % Spacing between lines
            \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}} % for spacing after each entry
            \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}} % for spacing after each entry
            \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}} % for spacing after each entry


        % Entries indentations

            % Labels widths
            \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0mm}

            \newlength{\widthcftsecnumwidth}
            \setlength{\widthcftsecnumwidth}{\widthof{1.2.3.~}}
            \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{\widthcftsecnumwidth}

            \newlength{\widthcftsubsecnumwidth}
            \setlength{\widthcftsubsecnumwidth}{\widthof{1.2.3.~~}}
            \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{\widthcftsubsecnumwidth}

            % prelabel content
            \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername}
            \renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{}
            \renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{}

            % Post label contents (usually empty space or new line)
            \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}\par} 

            % Labels indentations
            \setlength{\cftchapindent}{0mm}
            \setlength{\cftsecindent}{\widthof{\cftchapaftersnumb}}
            \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{\cftsecindent + \widthof{\cftsecaftersnumb} + \cftsecnumwidth}

        % Margins (see the LateX Companion, 51 for more details)

            \cftsetpnumwidth{8mm}

            \cftsetrmarg{2.5em plus 1fil}

        % Fonts

            % Definitions
            \newcommand{\toctitlefont}{\Large \bfseries} % font of the titles of lists (e.g., List of Tables)
            \newcommand{\tocchapfont}{\large \bfseries}
            \newcommand{\tocchappagefont}{\large \bfseries}
            \newcommand{\tocsecpagefont}{\large}
            \newcommand{\tocsubsecpagefont}{\normalfont} 

            % Titles and labels
            \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\toctitlefont}
            \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\tocchapfont}   
            \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\large} 
            \renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont} 

            % Numbering
            \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\tocchappagefont}   
            \renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\tocsecpagefont} 
            \renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\tocsubsecpagefont} 

        % Dots and spacing

            % Definitions
            \newcommand{\tocchapleaderformat}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
            \newcommand{\tocsecleaderformat}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

            % Dots
            \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\tocchapleaderformat}

                % To remove chapters dots from LoF and LoT, use 
                % \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\hfill}
                % Before \listoffigures and \listoftables

                % Leaders are also available for parts, sections, subsections, figures, and tables

            \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\tocsecleaderformat}

        % Names
        \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\color{\colorlink}\chaptername~} % chapter names
        \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\uppercase{Table of Contents}}
        \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\uppercase{List of Figures}}
        \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\uppercase{List of Tables}}

    % LoF and LoT customization

        % Spacing

            % Chapters, sections, and subsections
            \setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{\toclineskipl}

            % Main title
            \setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{5\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0\toclineskipl}
            \setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{5\toclineskipl}

            % Spacing between lines
            \renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}}
            \renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\vspace{\toclineskipl}}

        % Entries indentations

            % Labels widths
            \newlength{\widthcftfignumwidth}
            \setlength{\widthcftfignumwidth}{\widthof{1.2.3~}}
            \setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\widthcftfignumwidth}

            \newlength{\widthcfttabnumwidth}
            \setlength{\widthcfttabnumwidth}{\widthof{1.2.3~}}
            \setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\widthcfttabnumwidth}

            % Labels indentations
            \setlength{\cftfigindent}{0mm}
            \setlength{\cfttabindent}{0mm}

                % amount of left margin to the label

        % Fonts

            % Titles and labels
            \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\toctitlefont}
            \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\tocsecpagefont} 
            \renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\toctitlefont}
            \renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\tocsecpagefont} 

            % Numbering
            \renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\tocsecpagefont} 
            \renewcommand{\cfttabpagefont}{\tocsecpagefont} 

        % link colors
        \newcommand{\colorlink}{DodgerBlue3}



% END_FOLD

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}



\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter
{
\centering
{
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}
\listoffigures
}

\clearpage
{
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}
\listoftables
}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
}

\mainmatter

\newcommand{\figureandtable}{

\begin{figure}

    \caption{Impact of impedance ratios with different angles in the same quadrant on grid strength at the reference POI.}

\end{figure}

\begin{table}

    \caption{Top Five Weakest Combinations of POIs Identified with Exhaustive Search Method and the Proposed Method}

\end{table}

}



\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Background}

\subsection{Review of Control or Compensation Based Techniques to Mitigate Grid Weakness Symptoms}

\section{Background About Round-Off Errors During the Inversion of Ill-Conditioned Matrices}

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\figureandtable



\chapter{A Method to Identify Weak Points of Interconnection of Renewable Energy Resources}

\section{Proposed Method to Update ${Z}_{bus}$ to Account for Changes in the Series Impedance of a Branch}

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\chapter{Vector-Based Approach to Analyze Transmission Network Effect on Interaction Among Renewables}

\section{A Mathematical Basis for Understanding the Relationship Between Interaction and Structural Changes in Power Grid}

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\figureandtable

\subsection{Combined Effect of $\bar{w}_{ij}$ Angle and Magnitude Near When its Angle is Near $\pm 90^{\degree}$}



\end{document}
```