# Etoolbox's \patchcmd can't find search pattern due to hyperref package

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, etoolbox, report

I use the `report` class and I have learned from other questions on this site (like [Remove spacing between per-chapter figures in LoF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121879/remove-spacing-between-per-chapter-figures-in-lof)) how I can adjust the spacing between per-chapter figures in the LoF. I would like to change the traditional

`\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}`

in the report.cls file to

`\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{15\p@}}` by using this patch :

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}%
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% <search>
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{15\p@}}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

However, by issuing `\tracingpatches` I can see the following :

```
[debug] analyzing '\@chapter'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] -- search pattern not found in replacement text
```

Am I doing something wrong ? I don't understand why `\patchcmd` can't find the specified code. For the record, there are 3 other patches in my document (not modifying `\@chapter`) and they all work well.

**Edit:** While preparing a MWE, I realized that the package `hyperref` is the culprit, since removing it solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red]{hyperref}

%----------------------- Patch -----------------------
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}%        
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% <search>
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{15\p@}}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
%-----------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\appendix
\chapter{A chapter}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix this ? I need to keep loading the `hyperref` package.

Comment: show a small but complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Right, I will add a MWE as soon as I can

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've provided a MWE. Seems the culprit is the `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hyperref` has to define a great many internal commands to do its thing.

In this case the original definition of `\@chapter` is saved to `\Hy@org@chapter` by `hyperref`, `\@chapter` is then redefined to do some linking and then calls `\Hy@org@chapter`.

So the solution here is to patch `\Hy@org@chapter` instead of `\@chapter` when `hyperref` is loaded.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red]{hyperref}

%----------------------- Patch -----------------------
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}%        
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% <search>
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{15\p@}}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
%-----------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\appendix
\chapter{A chapter}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: larger spaces]

and

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 16
[debug] analyzing '\Hy@org@chapter'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] ++ search pattern found in replacement text
[debug] ++ patching possible
[debug] == retokenizing macro now
```

---

Alternatively, you can try to get your patch in *before* `hyperref` applies its redefinitions.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

%----------------------- Patch -----------------------
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}%        
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% <search>
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{15\p@}}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
%-----------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red]{hyperref}



\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\appendix
\chapter{A chapter}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) for suggesting that [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559565/etoolboxs-patchcmd-cant-find-search-pattern-due-to-hyperref-package/559592?noredirect=1#comment1411352_559592).

Comment: or perhaps less relying on internals, patch before loading hyperref

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very good point. Thank you. I've added your suggestion to the answer.