# ClassicThesis/ArsClassica and vertical space in list of figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, classicthesis

I am using the ClassicThesis with the ArsClassica package, which I love very much, but I have a problem with the vertical spacing in the list of figures between figures of different chapters.

My understanding is that ClassicThesis does not include an automatic vertical space between these figures, which is what I get when I run the code. Therefore I tried to add the vertical space in the following ways (I tried these one at a time):

```
%\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{5pt}}

%\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\vspace{-\cftbeforechapskip}}
```

Neither is working, i.e. there is no vertical space added and the list of figures stays at it is (please see the picture of the current state). I have also checked other proposed solutions, but none has worked thus far.

If somebody can help me with finding the correct code, that would be great!

Thanks!

[image]

UPDATE:
This solution solved the problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51074/158544

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121879/remove-spacing-between-per-chapter-figures-in-lof) might be useful (it deals with the opposite problem..). Hard to say more, as you don't provide sample code

Comment: @till Check what's `\deactivateaddvspace` from classicthesis.sty doing. Delete those several lines or renew it to \relax (What you tried doesn't make much sense to me, btw)

Comment: Thank you for your response. @PhilipPirrip, the provided link led to another response, which eventually worked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51074/158544